# Searching local date range Elastic Search

Tags: ajax, json, curl, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to search against a group of people, each of those people have dates which are in an array(localdate)

However I do not know how to search by a complete date. I tried "date:'1999,4'" as the date but it returns error.  I also tried doing this in cURL but it also returned error.

```
self.searchCriteria = "date:1999"

"http://leServer:9200/people/person/_search?q=" + self.searchCriteria
```

Which returns the following

```
        {
            "_index": "people",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "YRM33o5NSYa0ljHythDHrg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "date": [
                    1999,
                    4,
                    23
                ]
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any sensible way of searching such array. I can only suggest one of the following alternative solutions:

1. indexing it as a number `19990423` and use ranges for search
2. indexing it as a string `1999-04-23` and use wildcards for search
3. using elasticsearch `date` type and use ranges for search
4. indexing year, month, and date as 3 different fields

Comment: how can i use date type and use ranges in the search?

Comment: [Range queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query.html) support Date types. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/4496959

Comment: I guess I will have to convert the data I am indexing then I will be able to use that method. Thanks !